# how to enable additional login for http connector in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: https, jboss, connector

We have two java application running on the jboss 6.4 and one is calling to other using http call. it is working fine but few times in day conenction is failing with below error :
                CAUSED BY:
                java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)

Applcaction 1 is taking the request from the oracle queue and as per the asynchronous call sending the http call to applcation 2 . We would like to debug the issue of the failure to find the more info . how we can enable additional login between Htppconnector and httpclient ? or what could be the possible reason of Connection reset ?

We are using standalone-full.xml and it has below login level ::

```
<logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN" />
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN" />
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG" />
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN" />
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN" />
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR" />
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO" />
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE" />
                <handler name="FILE" />
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>

        --------

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2"
        default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http"
            socket-binding="http" />
        <connector name="HTTPS" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https"
            socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            ----------------------
        </connector>

        <virtual-server name="default-host"
            enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost" />
        </virtual-server>
        <valve name="AccessLog" module="org.jboss.as.web"
            class-name="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" enabled="true">
            <param param-name="prefix"
                param-value="${jboss.bind.address:xx.xx.xx}_${jboss.host.name:jboss}_access_log." />
            <param param-name="suffix" param-value=".log" />
            <param param-name="directory" param-value="${jboss.server.log.dir}" />
            <param param-name="pattern" param-value="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %D" />
            <param param-name="resolveHosts" param-value="false" />
            <param param-name="rotatable" param-value="true" />
        </valve>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable access logging by adding it in the web subsystem. It will log all coming requests and their outcomes.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">  
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>  
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">  
            <alias name="localhost"/>  
            <alias name="example.com"/>  
               <access-log pattern="%a %t %H %p %U %s " >  
                    <directory relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" />  
              </access-log>  
        </virtual-server>  
</subsystem>
```